# SQL SERVER : How to execute an SP specifed number of time without using loop

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario wherein i have to execute an SP for specified number of time(number of execution will be mentioned by user) without using loop. 
My SP is setting an OUTPUT variable of varchar type. I am willing to insert the output of my SP into a temp table and use it for further processing.

I am unable to modify this SP into function as it contain an Update statement.

Kindly suggest if we can do so without loop.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details as to why you cannot use a loop. You will need a counter of some kind and a way of repeating the stored procedure. Are you looking for a way of calling your SP from another SP?

Comment: Actually with current implementation we are using loops only but for better performance we are trying to eliminate loop. We have thought of following recursive CTE:                                                                                           ;with mycte as
(select 1 as i, 1 empid, 39 Stid, getDate() LastDt, 'abc' LUBy
union all
Select i+1 as i, 1, 39, getDate(), 'abc' From mycte Where i< @no
)
INSERT INTO xyz (empid,Stid,LastDt,LUBy)
SELECT empid,Stid,LastDt,LUBy
FROM   mycte   But in the select list there is one col which requirs to execute SP

Comment: @PS078 : Could you please share some sample implemented code so that we could help you better

Comment: If your requirement is "execute this stored procedure" then a loop is about the best you'll achieve, performance wise.

Comment: For recursive SQL see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit this solution you do not need an output; @res is your result directly set in a temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
    @Counter        int,
    @params         nvarchar(64),
    @CreateTable    bit
AS
DECLARE @res varchar(64)

IF @CreateTable = 1
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[#tempTable]'))
        DROP TABLE #tempTable

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable ([Res] [nvarchar] (64))
END

SET @res = CONVERT(varchar(64), @Counter)
SET @Counter = @Counter - 1

IF @Counter > 0
    exec myStoredProc @Counter, @params, 0

INSERT #tempTable VALUES (@res)

IF @CreateTable = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #tempTable
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
END
GO
DECLARE @o varchar(64)
exec [myStoredProc] 5, '', 1
```

Comment: @PS078 Was the solution useful?

Comment: Yes Simone, your solution has helped in my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: could you please select it as the answer :)